# Initializing private variables in typescript lead to corruption sometimes

Tags: typescript

Sometimes when i initialize variables into the method body, and i try to use the variables, it often end up undefined but if i declare it as a global variable(var variable name etc) it will work out fine, here is an example:

```
var num = 0;
module test{
export class tester{
    increment(){
        num++;
    }
}
}
```

that works fine but if i change the code to

```
module test{
export class tester{
    num : number;
    increment(){
        this.num++;
    }
}
}
```

it would give some gibberish or corrupted value it seems. This happened various times to me while coding in typescript but i often just make the variables global to solve it but i think this is bad practice. Is there a reason why this seems to occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize `num` with a value.

```
module test{
    export class tester{
        num : number = 0;
        increment(){
            this.num++;
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you're basically doing `undefined++` which is `NaN`.

Also, if you want to make a variable private then you should explicitly mark it as private by doing `private num : number = 0;`